# remove all letters after space in a line that start with specific character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have big fasta file, I want to remove all letter after first space in a header line that start with specific character/symbol (`>`).

Here is an example input file:

```
>AB3446 human helix ACGTGAGATGGATAGA 
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567 human beta sheet 
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
$ cat file.fasta 
>AB3446 human helix ACGTGAGATGGATAGA 
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567 human beta sheet 
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

then

```
$ sed '/^>/ s/ .*//' file.fasta 
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

replaces everything from the first space (inclusive) onward on every line that starts with `>`

---

Alternatively, with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^>/ {$0=$1} 1' file.fasta 
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the example data from your question is stored in `file.txt`, you could use `sed` to process the text and remove everything after (and including) the first whitespace character in each line starting with a `>`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(>\S+)\s.*/\1/' file.txt
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

If the command `sed -r 's/^(>\S+)\s.*/\1/' file.txt` produces the right output for you, you can tell it to modify the given file in-place, instead of just showing the output, by adding the `-i` option to this `sed` command:

```
sed -r -i 's/^(>\S+)\s.*/\1/' file.txt
```

What this does is simple. `-r` enables extended regular expressions, giving us more functionality to define regex patterns in our command, which is `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` here.

`PATTERN` is the regular expression `^(>\S+)\s.*` which matches a `>` character at the beginning of a line (`^`) followed by at least one non-whitespace character (`\S+`), a whitespace character (`\s`, could be a normal blank, tab, etc.) and then the whole rest of the line (`.*` is any number of any characters).

`REPLACEMENT` is `\1` which tells `sed` to use the content of the first capture group (what got matched by the pattern inside the leftmost pair of round parentheses `(...)`) from the matched line as replacement. In our case, this is everything up to the first whitespace, exclusively.

Comment: It is very nice answer. Worked perfectly...Thanks

Comment: Nice. If it solved your question, please don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the grey round check button on its left. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## portable shell way

With use of word splitting:

```
$ while read -r one two;do echo "$one" ;done < input.txt                    
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

With use of `case` and parameter substitution:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line;do case "$line" in ">"*) printf "%s\n" "${line%% *}";;*)printf "%s\n" "$line";;esac ;done < input.txt                                        
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

## Perl

```
$ perl -lane '$_=$F[0] if $F[0] =~ /^>/;print' input.txt                                                                                                               
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

#### not portable bash way

```
$ bash -c 'for((i=0;;i++)); do IFS= read -r line || break; [[ $line =~ ^\> ]] && line=${line/ */} ;echo "$line" ;done' < input.txt                                     
>AB3446
GATAGATAGATAGACACA 
>AH4567
ACGTGATAGATGAGACGATGCCC 
CACGGGTATATAGCCCAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming others lines contain only one word (as in the example), this is pretty straight forward :

```
cut -f 1 -d " " file.fasta
```