# How to grep sequence of fasta using list of IDs in another file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a big file of fasta sequence and a list of IDs. I need to `grep` some sequences with header using their IDs from another file. Here, is the files examples.

File 1:

```
>AB1234
ACGTAGATA
>AB3456
ACGATAGAT
>AB4567
ACGTGTGA
```

File 2

```
>AB1234
>AB3456
```

Comment: Generic programming questions are better suited for stackexchange.com

Comment: @MichaelBay Is this a generic programming question?

Comment: Which is the id file here?

Comment: @George I think it is and the OP's other question as well. So, a pattern is being shown. But if you want to answer it I'm not stopping you ;)

Comment: @George So far the OP asked two questions. So, when I say "OP's other question" it must be https://askubuntu.com/questions/974459/remove-all-letters-after-space-in-a-line-that-start-with-specific-character Now, how are both questions related to Ubuntu? Answers for both are applicable to pretty much any Linux distro and beyond therefore better suited to main SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `grep` read patterns from a file, one pattern per line, with the `-f` option:

```
grep -x -F -A 1 -f 'File 2' 'File 1'
```

Additionally,

- `-F` interprets patterns literally and not as regular expressions,
- `-x` only matches entire lines,
- `-A N` prints `N` lines following each match.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work:

```
for i in $(cut -d" " -f1- file2); do grep -o "$i" file1 | tee -a result.txt; done
```

Assumption `file1` == `id` file, and `file2` == file to be greped

Result.txt:

```
AB1234
AB3456
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the id file and the expected outcome